# javascript weakmap keep refrence to deleted object

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, weakmap

when delete the object , `weakmap` keeps refrence to it.
but the normal behaviour is : when oyu delete the object it will removed from weakmap automatically and weakmap cannot cause memory leak.
is it something wrong with `weakmap` or `delete` ?

```
let a =  { aa : { aa : 123 } };
const w = new WeakMap();
w.set(a.aa,"hello");
delete a.aa
console.log(w);// shows that '{aa:123}' is still there in weakmap
```

i've closed and open the devtool and `{aa:123}` is still there.
expect `weakmap` to be empty

Comment: thanks to @komal-bansal this question has been answered already in this link . so flagged as duplicate :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49841518/2611020

Answer (score 3):

Your `delete()` function should look like this:

```
 w.delete(a.aa);
```

Comment: you're right , but my problem is not deleting something from weakmap .  
weakmap are known as something that has weak reference .  
this means that when you remove the object that has a reference in weakmap , the weak cannot prevent the object from `gc` . so weakmap does not cause memory leak .   but in my code even though i'm deleting the object , weakmap prevent `gorbage collector` from removing the object . my question is why weakmap do such a thing ?  
look and try this can help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43579723/2611020

Answer (score 0):

You are using delete operator instead of delete property of weak map.

```
var a =  { aa : { aa : 123 } };
var w = new WeakMap();
w.set(a.aa,"hello");
console.log(a.aa)
w.delete(a.aa); // try this 
console.log(w);
```

Docs [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap/delete)

Comment: my question is not removing something from weakmap . my Q is : the point of weakmap is : when you delete object that has a reference in weakmap , weakmap remove the object inside , so that `gc` be able to remove the object from memory . but in my case even though i'm deleting object weakmap hold the reference to object and this cause `gc` to fail at removing object `{aa:123}` . this can help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43579723/2611020

Comment: I think you can get , what you are looking for from here 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49841096/javascriptes6-weakmap-garbage-collection-when-set-an-object-to-null

Comment: oh my god . yes that's the answer . thank you so very much

Answer (score 0):

However I have not worked with `weakmap` but the reason behind not deleting through

`delete a.aa`

is just because `w` is separate reference to the object rather `pointer` to the same object.

> Simple values (aka scalar primitives) are always assigned/passed by value-copy: null, undefined, string, number, boolean, and ES6's symbol.
>
> Compound values -- objects (including arrays, and all boxed object wrappers -- see Chapter 3) and functions -- always create a copy of the reference on assignment or passing.

consider the below snippet:

```
function foo(x) {
 x.push( 4 );
 x; // [1,2,3,4]

 // later
 x = [4,5,6];
 x.push( 7 );
 x; // [4,5,6,7]
}

var a = [1,2,3];

foo( a );

a; // [1,2,3,4]  not  [4,5,6,7]
```

> When we pass in the argument a, it assigns a copy of the a reference to x. x and are a separate references pointing at the same [1,2,3] value. Now, inside the function, we can use that reference to mutate the value itself (push(4)). But when we make the assignment x = [4,5,6], this is in no way affecting where the initial reference a is pointing -- still points at the (now modified) [1,2,3,4] value.

Give it a read to [this](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch2.md#value-vs-reference)!

Hope it makes it clear!

Comment: no weakmap is not the same as normal object . weakmap is called `weak` because it holds a weak reference to object and this `weak reference` means that when you delete the object itself > it will removed from weakmap automatically and the weak reference inside `w` cannot prevent `gorbage collector` from removing the object.
look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43579723/2611020